# Select IDs where ID not in another table not working?

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm using Vertica SQL

Two tables:

```
Table1
ID,Sales
1,50 
2,0
3,60
..

Table2
ID,sales
3,50
4,55
5,60
...
```

```
select count(distinct id) from table1 where sales >0; 
--returns about 50
select count(distinct id) from table2 where sales >0; 
--returns about 20
```

```
select count(distinct t1.id) from table1 t1 where t1.sales >0 and t1.id not in (select distinct(t2.id) from table2 t2 where t2.sales >0);
--returns 0
```

How is this possible if table1 has more records than table2 with the given conditions?

ID is varchar and sales is numeric

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have no records in your table1 that have sales in table1, but no sales in table2. It's got nothing to do with counts when queries separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do this with a join:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.id) as id_count
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT id
 FROM table2
 WHERE sales > 0) sub
ON t1.id = sub.id
WHERE sub.id IS NULL
AND t1.sales > 0
```

It doesn't read as pretty but there may be performance advantages.

Comment: This works as well. It was the null values getting me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is your query:

```
select count(distinct t1.id)
from table1 t1
where t1.sales > 0 and
      t1.id not in (select distinct t2.id from table2 t2 where t2.sales > 0);
```

`not in` is a dangerous construct.  If *any* row in the subquery has a `NULL` value for `id`, then *no* rows are returned at all by the outer query.  For this reason, I strongly recommend using `not exists` for such logic:

```
select count(distinct t1.id)
from table1 t1
where t1.sales > 0 and
      not exists (select 1from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t2.sales > 0);
```

Comment: That does it. There must have been null values, much thanks!